# jQuery selection with filter and exclusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to select all  of class .Tag that are not the element passed to the function

Here's what I got:

```
$("a.tag").filter(":visible").not("\"[id='" + aTagID + "']\"").each(
    function place(index, element) {
        log("  checking element " + element.id);
});
```

aTagID is passed to this function and is the ID of the calling element that I want to exclude from the selection. log is a function that simply does a console.log.

Here is what I get in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "[id='t1']"
```

Comment: Tell it to the duck principle strikes again! In documenting the problem I got the solution: the double quotes aren't needed. It works when I take them off. .not([id='t1']) is what it should look like.

Comment: Haha I believe they call that **Rubber duck debugging** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in one selector (`#` can be used instead of an attribute selector for id):

```
$("a.tag:visible:not(#" + aTagID + ")").each(
```

Comment: Yes, this works much better. I tried it before but had the same problem - put quotes around it. I do prefer to use the .not() though. makes the code a bit clearer. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `:not` in your filter as well as using the ID selector `#`:

```
$("a.tag").filter(":visible:not(#" + aTagID + ")").each(function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

Should it not be:

```
$("a.tag").filter(":visible").not("\"#id='" + aTagID\")").each(function() {
```

The [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) jQuery method takes a selector. I don't believe `"[id='t1']"` will work.

OR you could try using the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$("a.tag").filter(":visible:not(#" + aTagID + ")").each(function() {
```